# Авторизация пользователей в facebook на сайте

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api, auth

Добрый день.
Не могу настроить авторизацию пользователей в facebook.
Создал приложение и разместил кнопку "Войти", кнопка работает, авторизоваться и "лайкнуть" получается, но не могу получить доступ к данным авторизовавшегося пользователя.

Каким образом можно настроить запрос на доступ данных пользователя в приложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался.
Не правильно передавал ID пользователя

```
FB.init({ 
    appId : '___________', // App ID 
    status : false, // check login status 
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session 
    oauth : true, // enable oauth 
    xfbml : true // parse XFBML 
});
```

Это инициализация Facebook API

```
FB.api("/ID_user", function (response) {console.log(response)});
```